# Dirac's "Principles of Quantum Mechanics", Electron Spin

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, angular-momentum, electrons, quantum-spin

In Section 37 (The spin of the electron), Dirac writes,

> "The eigenvalues of $m_z$ are $\hbar/2$ and $-\hbar/2$, so the eigenvalues of $\sigma_z$ are 1 and -1, and $\sigma_z^2$ has just the one eigenvalue 1. It follows that $\sigma_z^2$ must be 1, and similarly for $\sigma_x^2$ and $\sigma_y^2$..."

I understand why $\sigma_z^2=1$, but why does $\sigma_x^2=1=\sigma_y^2$?

Comment: The eigenvalues of all Pauli matrices are the same!

Comment: There’s nothing special about the $z$-direction.

Comment: I’ll just follow the theory, then. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: all Pauli matrices are strictly equivalent to each other, so they have the same eigenvalues, $\pm 1$, hence their squares are degenerate, so, identity matrices, and therefore identical.

Specifically, you may [trivially](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices#Exponential_of_a_Pauli_vector) check the equivalence relations
$$
e^{-i\pi \sigma_y/4}~ \sigma_z ~e^{i\pi \sigma_y/4} = \sigma_x \\
e^{-i\pi \sigma_z/4}~ \sigma_x ~e^{i\pi \sigma_z/4} = \sigma_y ~~,
$$
consistently and geometrically.

NB (Geeky) <sub>Note the above argument is not circular. That is, even though the calculational shortcut linked above   utilizes properties of the Pauli matrices (which you are trying to explore), the above two rotations by π/2 are pure Lie-algebraic properties of rotating generators ([Hadamard's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula#An_important_lemma_and_its_application_to_a_special_case_of_the_Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula)) and hold for *all representations*, so you never *really* needed the shortcut relations. The eigenvalues of all three generators are the same in all representations!</sub>